# How to align two elements on the same line html

Tags: html

I have an example like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xmeovze/) where I have a list of `<a>` element. Inside each `<a>` element I have a `<span>` and a `<button>`. What I would like to do is I want to align the button on the right, I do this by adding the class `pull-right` and it worked fine

```
<button class=" btt pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></button>
```

, and I want to align the `span` and the `button` on the same line, but if I have a very long Name inside the span then the button is no longer on the same line with the span. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just position the buttons as `alternative` and put it `right: 0` to align it to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width and display property to the span elements like this:

```
.surveySummaryList a span {
      width: calc(100% - 40px);
      display: inline-block;
      word-break: break-all;
}
```

and add rule for your buttons width like this:

```
.btt{
    width: 30px;
}
```

I updated the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5xmeovze/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute;` in your styling and set the buttons `right` styling to `0`. This will place your button at an absolute position, according to your parental `div`.

```
.btt {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/5xmeovze/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have faced a few times and usually what I do is decide the maximum length I will allow this value to be and then truncate after that with ellipsis.

It is up to you but I think this is a good choice to make as it is defensive coding to keep your display neat no matter what the value.

Here is an example CSS class you can add to your span:

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```